# Wordpress Navigation default output

Tags: menus, navigation

Could someone please give me the Wordpress default navigation output, i've searched it around but havn't found it.

I would like the example navigation to also include one sub-menu link.

Or if someone could point me out to a link where i could find information about this and customizing, thanks.

Comment: I do not understand this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) is what you are looking for.

Here are some [examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Examples).

Using the depth parameter you can change the level of sub-menu.

0 leads to all levels.

Ex.

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```